# How to submit a form via jQuery if url-parameter is given?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a form be submitted if there is a trigger-parameter in the url. I so far added a code-snippet so automatically insert the parameter into the input field.

This is my current code, working perfectly when using the submit-button or Enter.

e.g => website.com/?lookup=value

```
<form  method="post" name="formid" id="formid">
     <?php $paraid = $_GET['lookup']; ?>   
          <input class="form-control" id="steamid" name="s" value="<?php echo $paraid; ?>" > 
              <input type="submit" id="invbtn"  value="submit" />
      </form>

      <script>
        $('#formid').submit(function() {
          var id = $("#steamid").val().replace(/(?:https?\:)?\/\//i, '');
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "s="+id,
            url: 'steam.php',
            beforeSend:function() {
              $("#outputinfo").html("<center><img src='./assets/img/load.gif'></br></br>Wait...</center>");
            },success: function(html) {
              $("#outputinfo").html(html);
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var id = '<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>';
          if (id != null) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              data: "s="+id,
              url: 'steam.php',
              beforeSend:function() {
                $("#outputinfo").html("<center><img src='./assets/img/load.gif'></br></br>Wait...</center>");
              },success: function(html) {
                $("#outputinfo").html(html);
              }
            });
          }
          return false;
        });
      </script>
```

Thanks in advance.. i hope you guys can help me out..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To submit a form if it has a certain word in the url use:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['lookup'}) == 'value') :?> //whatever website.com/?lookup=value is
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formid').submit();
});
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: okay nice! but its a 50% chance that the result doesnt disappear.. when i enter the url ist shows the content in the output div (<div id="outputinfo">  </div>) but then in 5 out of 10 times the div gets cleared again..

Comment: It seems that the code is all running at the same time, which means the form submits before the other's have finished loading. Make sure both ajax forms are within "$(document).ready(function(){" and place the php code so that the $('#formid').submit(); script is at the bottom of the page. You could also try changing the submit to $(window).load(function(){ so it submits after the ajax calls are done.

Comment: Isset returns true or false, hence the comparison will never be true. Moreover, is the closing brace really supposed to be curly?

Comment: $(window).load(function() did the job thank you very very much

Comment: sorry for bothering you again :/ i tested to code on a blank page with only the form.. now i copy&paste the code on my website (one-page-website) and tried to use it.. when i enter the value manually into the input field and click on submit it works fine, but when i use the url with parameter [link](http://matchme.16mb.com/?lookup=triban1337) i cant scroll down to the form or the <div id="outputinfo></div> because it brings me back to the top of the page every 5 seconds. And the form doesnt get submitted i dont even see the loading.gif or any results as on the test page